# How can I trigger the dropdown from within a component

Tags: dropdown, ngx-bootstrap

I'm building an angular application where the user should be able to right-click the canvas (this covers most of the page) and see a context menu. I've been using the ngx-bootstrap dropdown for the main menu of the app and want to use the same module for this context menu. 
The demo of this dropdown menu shows a manual toggle using a button with

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (onclick)="dropdown.toggle(true);">Toggle</button>
```

If I try this: 
Component.html

```
<div id="canvas" (contextmenu)="handleRightClick($event)">
</div>
```

Component.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my',
  templateUrl: './my.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my.component.scss']
})
export class MyComponent {
    constructor() {
    }
    handleRightClick(e) {
        dropdown.toggle(true);
    }
}
```

When right clicking the canvas I get an error:

```
ReferenceError: dropdown is not defined
```

The fact that I get the error does not surprise me. I did not declare this "dropdown" variable anywhere. My question is: how do I get access to this dropdown from Component.ts

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a template variable to a dropdown directive `#dropdown="bs-dropdown"` and this variable will work in the template, but if you need to manage dropdown's state from component's code you have to use `@ViewChild` to get a reference to a dropdown and it will look somewhat like this `@ViewChild('dropdown') dropdown: BsDropdownDirective;`

here's an example - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gnvgjn